# How to serve tiff WMS imagery through GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am new to the GeoServer/database world. I have never done any database work before, but I need to set up a WMS using GeoServer as part of my student internship.

I am using GeoServer 2.0.1 in standalone mode (downloaded using Jetty) with PostgreSQL 8.4 installed.  I went through `nyc_roads` and `nyc_buildings` install demo in the GeoServer documentation but I still do not understand how I should go about serving up some test images. I noticed that the `nyc_roads` setup included a .sql file that was responsible for setting up the `nyc_buildings` database.  I do not know how/where this file was generated.

Our test images are .tiff and .jpeg.  I have successfully been able to do a WMS call on the local GeoServer machine, and have opened the included demo imagery.  I now wish to add these .tiff and .jpeg images to GeoServer and access them through WMS. I have tried copying the images to the GeoServer data directory, adding a new data store and layers, but I always receive an error regarding the `input stream`.

I am sorry if I am leaving out vital information, this is as much as I know.

---

EDIT:

As described in the comment below, I am confused as to why GeoServer wont publish a GeoTiff image layer.  I've made a separate workspace and data store for it.  When I go to add the GeoTiff image, the bounding boxes/Geo coordinates are read properly, along with the correct EPSG format.  When I'm happy with the settings, I click save, but nothing happens.  No error messages or warnings.

Comment: Are your images GeoTifs? Do your images have world files?
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/geotiff.html

Comment: yes they are GeoTifs and I do not believe they have world files.  I have not come across them

Comment: I have gone through the steps multiple times and I still do not understand why geoserver will not publish my geotiff layer.  Geoserver successfully loads the bounding boxes from the image along with the proper EPSG SRS.  Whenever I hit save however, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try runinng the GDAL info tool to see if there is anython strange in the geotiffs and post the results here http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html

Answer (score 3):

Upload your GeoTIFF (*.tif) file to a folder on your server.

Open GeoServer home.  Sign in to the server (default user admin pwd geoserver).  Select WORKSPACES on the left menu.

[image]

Create a new workspace and call it whatever you want.
[image]

Create a new store 
[image]

and choose GeoTIFF.
[image]

Click on the BROWSE button next to the fileName and select your GeoTIFF.
[image]

If it is properly created, the bounding box should appear with the correct coordinates.  Select WMS service (VERY IMPORTANT).

Check [this tutorial](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_geotiff.html) for a complete run through.

Call WMS layer from JavaScript using Openlayers.